# Не понятен смысл DI

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Мне не до конца понятен смысл использование **DI** (например *autofac*). Возможно, я не правильно трактую его смысл из-за неверной области применения.

Контекст задачи следующий: необходимо внедрить *autofac* модуль в систему тестирования. Собственно проблема, зачем мне писать код с разрешением зависимостей через тот же *autofac* если могу явно создавать объекты и передовать их в конструктор.

К примеру, есть *ApiController*, у него в конструкторе куча аргументов типа пользовательского контекста, менеджера регистрации, менеджера для отправки смс и т.д. Все эти объекты в свою очередь тоже достаточно сложно инициализируются. К примеру:

### Вариант с Autofac

```
ISomeClassInterface someClass;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SomeService>();
var container = builder.Build();
someClass = new SomeClass(container.Resolve<SomeService>();
```

### Вариант без Autofac'a

```
ISomeClassInterface someClass;
ISomeService service = new SomeService(some arguments...);
someClass = new SomeClass(service);
```

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы не поняли в чем преимущетсво DI потому что вы в вашем примере все так же передаете ваш `SomeService` как аргумент в конструкторе класса `SomeClass`. А я так понимаю что Ваш `container.Resolve` должен возвращать `SomeClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос: "Все эти объекты в свою очередь тоже достаточно сложно инициализируются". Чем сложнее, тем проще ошибиться. Безусловно, можно не использовать никакой DI. Но, во-первых, DI упрощает инициализацию объектов. Во-вторых, DI упрощает подмену объектов. Например, вы захотите использовать другой менеджер регистрации. Без DI придется менять код в нескольких местах, с DI - в одном.

Сравните:

```
A a = new A(new B(new C()), new D(new E())...);
```

И как-то условно

```
A a = container.Resolve<A>();
```

Comment: Но ведь в этом случае DI создаст какие то фиктивные параметры и передаст их в конструктор, или я ошибаюсь? Если нет, то можно в ваш первый пример, и какой нибудь mock'er прикрутить.

Comment: Момент, если у меня в решении несколько проектов, некоторые из них будут гарантированно запущены при выполнении тестов. Можно ли инициализировать объекты уже созданным в каком либо проекте объектом? К примеру, у меняв Core создается менеджер регистрации, дак вот, возможно ли передать ссылку на этот объект в apiController?

Comment: Он "зарезолвит" только те типы, которые ранее были зарегистрированы в контейнере. Согласен, в самом юнит тесте можно обойтись без DI.

Comment: Думаю можно, надо смотреть документации отдельного DI.